# How can I remove all documents from a SharePoint 2010 Web Application

Tags: 2010, powershell, web

We would like to restore our entire production environment in our stage environment.  After completing the restore, we would like to strip out all the documents to just leave the "structure" behind.   Is there a good script out there to accomplish this?

Comment: how many site collections in the web app?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how many site collections are there in your environment but if there aren't many why don't you create site templates (without content) and then restore them in the staging environment.

You can save your site as template even with the publishing feature using the following powershell command,

```
$Web=Get-SPWeb http://Servername:port/yourSite
$Web.SaveAsTemplate("Template Name","Template Title","Template Description",0)
```

In the forth parameter of SaveAsTemplate(), if you want to save the specified site as template along with data use 1, otherwise use 0.
After successfully running above commands, the newly created template will be available in site collection "Solutions" gallery.

You can then restore these in your new farm.

Also, you can use this must have open source tool to achieve the desired results: http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/